# pop up a html page or window to display a response

Tags: javascript, jquery

I got a response from a server, the text format of the response is

> ```
>   "<div class=\"esv\"><h2>John 3:16 <object type=\"application/x-shockwave-flash\"  data=\"http://www.esvapi.org/assets/play.swf?myUrl=hw%2F43003016\" width=\"40\" height=\"12\" class=\"audio\"><param name=\"movie\" value=\"http://www.esvapi.org/assets/play.swf?myUrl=hw%2F43003016\" /><param name=\"wmode\" value=\"transparent\" /></object></h2>\n<div class=\"esv-text\"><h3 id=\"p43003016.01-1\">For God So Loved the World</h3>\n<p id=\"p43003016.07-1\"><span class=\"verse-num woc\" id=\"v43003016-1\">16&nbsp;</span><span class=\"woc\">&#8220;For God so loved the world,<span class=\"footnote\">&nbsp;<a href=\"#f1\" id=\"b1\" title=\"Or 'For this is how God loved the world'\">[1]</a></span> that he gave his only Son, that whoever believes in him should not perish but have eternal life.</span>  (<a href=\"http://www.esv.org\" class=\"copyright\">ESV</a>)</p>\n</div>\n<div class=\"footnotes\">\n<h3>Footnotes</h3>\n<p><span class=\"footnote\"><a href=\"#b1\" id=\"f1\">[1]</a></span> <span class=\"footnote-ref\">3:16</
>     span> Or <em>For this is how God loved the world</em>\n</p>\n</div>\n</div>"
> ```

The html format likes [image]

Any skill can pop up this message in javascript or jquery?

Comment: you could use jquery ui dialog http://jqueryui.com/dialog/ or twitter bootstrap popover

Comment: I just worry the displaying mess up...

Comment: HTML is strictly KJV only... sorry :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want a nice looking popup in the middle of your screen (not the standard javascript alert popups), then...

For the div you have above, you can

1) position it in the center of your screen (read http://www.jakpsatweb.cz/css/css-vertical-center-solution.html) You may want to style the div with `position: fixed;`, depending on how your website is set up. Also set `z-index: 999;` or some other high number.

2) hide it. For example in the CSS set `.esv {display: none}`

3) using jQuery/javascript, display it when whatever event you want occurs

```
$("#somebutton").click(function(){
         $(".esv").show(); // will display the popup window
    }
```

This is a very simplified model. But something along these lines might be what you want.
If you want to have different content each time, then you can at first have your `<div class="esv"></div>` empty. Then use jQuery to insert whatever you desire into before `show()`.  However you will have to research how to dynamically select whatever you are inserting.

So step 3 might look like this:

```
 $("#somebutton").click(function(){
         $(".esv").html( /* whatever html you want to insert. */);
         $(".esv").show(); // will display the popup window
    }
```